# indistinctness about knockout in combination with mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a few problems using knockout in combination with the mapping pluging. (using knockout 3.0.0 and knockout.mapping 2.4.0)

I have a viewmodel function:

```
ViewModel(){
   ....add extra functionality here for button click functions etc.

};
```

and want to instantiate a viewmodel at startup:

```
 var myViewModel = {};

 $(function () {
     //converting data received from asp.net to json.
     var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()))';

     myViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel);
     ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
 });
```

I tried some overloads of the fromJSON function (but they don't seem to work anymore):

```
myViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel, {}, new ViewModel());
```

and

```
myViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel, new ViewModel());
```

Also initiating the myViewModel to a new instance of ViewModel and passing in the myViewModel objects doesn't affect the outcome.

also a ViewModel Function with input data doesn't seem to work:

```
function ViewModel(sourceData) {
        var self = this;
        this.data = ko.mapping.fromJSON(sourceData);

        //----- Open modal for editing customer
        self.OpenEditModal = function () {
            $('#customerModal').modal({ show: true });
        };
    };

    var myViewModel = {};

    $(function () {
        var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()))';
        myViewModel = new ViewModel(jsonModel);
        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
    });
```

How do i add functionality to the viewmodel ?

update: added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Speedy7912/d8uVD/2/ 
p.s. extra problem: when binding function to click event, 2nd record isn't shown.

Comment: Can you please put together a simple JSFiddle which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: added fiddle. (see post).

Comment: I don't understand your problem with the mapping: in your fiddle the data is displayed fine. Regarding your click problem: in your fiddle there is no click binding on the edit button: if I add one it is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vthgL/

Comment: the '$parent.' is the solution. I added the click binding using '$root.' Where can I find more info on javascript for understanding how an object should and can be bound for my problem. I'm more a backend developer as an javascript programmer. With Asp.net MVC I should be both.

Comment: Your code is working fine also with `$root`: http://jsfiddle.net/t7b9V/ you can read more about the mapping plugin http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html and the binding cotext http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html in the official documentation.